# Additional Client Information BESIDES Cookies

Tags: cookies, client

How can a website "remember" user information aside from cookies?

For example, there was a time when I was browsing on a newspaper website (*New York Times*), and I had reached the ten limit article count. Usually, I just deleted the cookies, and that would bring the article count back to zero and I could continue browsing again.

However, lately, deleting all the cookies on my computer no longer works as a way to bypass this article count block. As such, I was curious as to what other possible ways could be used to "remember" one's user information (in this case, the number of articles a user has browsed) aside from cookies.

There was also another instance where I was forever banished from a site; deleting my cookies again didn't work in accessing it - the site somehow had a way of "remembering" who the banned users were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious answer is your IP address.

While not perfect, [IP address blocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_blocking) can be used to identify you and deny you access.
In particular, its commonly used to detect what country a visitor is coming from to enforce content distribution laws.